# Raspberry pi zero interface with gsm/gprs module

Tags: linux, gsm, gprs, sim800, raspberry-pi-zero

I am new to raspberry pi zero and I want to connect it with gsm module for gprs connectivity .
I bought sim800a gsm module but its led not even blinking single time
I am able to turn on the UART on pi zero and coonect it over usb cable through ssh .
Can anyone help me out how to achieve what I want and also suggest a better gsm module for gprs if sim800a is not good enough